# how do I change the regex to get the desired one?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to check a string where at the end the to symbols are mandatory, first is '@' and the second is given with the t variable.

I have got this:

```
var t = 0;
var p = /^[a-z0-9A-Z_-]*@$/ + t.toString();

p.test("asdf2@0");
```

and get always 'false'

how to add the t String to the RegExp of p variable

Now, I have searched a bit and found out that people do use RegExp constructor:

```
var t = 0;
var re = new RegExp("^\/\\[a-z0-9A-Z_-]*@" + t.toString() + "\/\\$");
var z = re.test("asdf2@0");
```

in this case z is always 'false'.

what I am doing wrong? Can you please, also explain what \ means exactly and why and where to apply it in the RegExp.

Comment: Why are you starting and ending your _RegExp_ with /\?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` signals the end of the input string, so you need to add the variable value before it. To do so you must use the explicit Regexp object instead of the simplified version. Try the following:

```
var t = 0;
var p = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9A-Z_-]*@" + t + "$");
```

Answer (score 0):

What are all the backslashes you have in that regex? I assume some of them are being interpreted as characters, and they aren't in your test string. If you remove them, it works just fine.